# how can i calculate Estimate time using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two columns **start_time** and **end_time** and calculate time according to them.
like i have **start_time** is 0300AM and **end_time** is 0430AM, my calculate time will be as 0300AM:0330AM:0400AM
how can i do ?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (start_time, end_time) as
  2    (select '0300am', '0430am' from dual),
  3  dates as
  4    (select to_date(start_time, 'hhmiam') cst,
  5            to_date(end_time, 'hhmiam') cet
  6     from test
  7    )
  8  select listagg(to_char(cst + 30/(24*60) * (level - 1), 'hhmiam'), ':')
  9         within group (order by level) result
 10  from dates
 11  connect by level <= (cet - cst) * 24 * 2;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0300AM:0330AM:0400AM

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #1 - 2: sample data
- CTE `dates` (lines #3 - 7) convert sample data into `date` datatype
- hierarchical query (lines #8 - 11):

  - `to_char`'s parameter adds 30 minutes (`30/(24*60)`) to start time (`cst`) multiplied by number of 30-minutes occurrences within the end time *minus* start time period (`cet - cst` in line #11) which is multiplied by `24` (number of hours in a day, as result of subtraction of two dates is number of days) and `2` (two 30-minutes periods within an hour)
  - `to_char` itself formats the result into desired format
  - `listagg` aggregates the result, separating values by colon `:`